# Java - How to make two similar for loops into one loop

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I have two similar loops and I was asked to eliminate one of them but I don't know how to..

Here's my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Tree {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter height: ");
    int tmp = input.nextInt();

    int x = (tmp-1)*2+1;
    int y = x/2;
    int z = 1;

    for(int i=0; i<tmp; i++){

        for(int j=0; j<=y; j++){
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        for(int k=0; k<z; k++){
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println();
        y--;
        z+=2;
    }
    for(int i=0; i<tmp; i++){
        y++;
        for(int j=0; j<=y; j++){
            System.out.print(" ");
        }

        z-=2;
        for(int k=0; k<z; k++){
            System.out.print("*");
        }

        System.out.println();

    }

}

}
```

Should I code up a method and call it?

I am struggling for days..

Hope for a simple suggestion because I am just a beginner level student.

Your help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem should be considered at a higher level:

What you want to have (based on your code) is a two dimensional matrix of `*` and  representing a diamond, so let's try to have a solution with two for loops, corresponding to the two dimensions of the matrix/screen, with some condition to define the rendering of each "pixel":

```
// vertical dimension (i:= line index)
for (int i =0; i< 2* tmp +1 ; ++i){
        if(i!=tmp){ //handling of middle-line corner case

            // horizontal dimension (j:= row index)
            for (int j=0; j< 2*tmp ; ++j){
                if (condition(tmp, i,j)){
                    System.out.print("*");
                }else{
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }
            }

            if(i!=2 * tmp) { // handling of last line corner case
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean condition(int tmp, int i, int j) {

        // return true if and only if the (i, j) pixel is within the central diamond
        return Math.abs(tmp-i) + Math.abs(tmp-j) <= tmp;        
    }
```

The two handling of corner cases are just to match your result.

Answer (score 0):

Consider removing this loop first:

```
for(int k=0; k<z; k++){
System.out.print("*");
}
```

to remove this run the previous loop up to end, which means run previous loop up to y+z, then put one if condition to print * or space.

Answer (score 0):

The most trivial clean-up consists of introducing an abstraction by way of a function:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print("Enter height: ");
int height = input.nextInt();

int x = (height-1)*2+1;
int y = x/2;
int z = 1;

for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
    printRepeated(y, " ");
    printRepeated(z, "*");
    System.out.println();
    y--;
    z += 2;
}
for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
    y++;
    z -= 2;
    printRepeated(y, " ");
    printRepeated(z, "*");
    System.out.println();
}
```

with a help function:

```
private void printRepeated(int repetitions, String s) {
    System.out.print(String.format("%" + repetitions + "s", "").replace(" ", s));
}
```

If you express `y` and `z` in terms of `x` and `i` you might merge the loops.
For the second loop `for (i = height; i < x; ++i)`. I leave that as a puzzle.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting problem!

One way to think about printing this diamond on the screen is to see how many times spaces are printed and how many times asterisks are printed in each of the `2*h` lines where `h` is the height given. So, you definitely need two loops (one inside another) -- one to count the lines and one to count the contents of each line. But you can avoid the repetition of those two loops that your program does. One trick is to choose the range of the index of the *outer* loop such that although that index follows a monotonic sequence (e.g. `1, 2, ..., n`) and yet the *inner* loop indices follow an alternating sequence (e.g. `1, 2, ..., k, k, k-1, k-2, ..., 1`).

There are perhaps several ways to do this, but the following seems to do the job well. It takes help of the `Math.abs` function:

```
public static void printDiamond(int h) {
    int ns; // number of spaces
    int na; // number of asterisks
    for (int i = -h; i < h; i++) {
        ns = i == 0 ? 1 : (i < 0 ? Math.abs(i) : i + 1);
        na = i == 0 ? (2*h - 1) : (i < 0 ? (2 * h) - (2 * Math.abs(i))  + 1 : (2 * h) - (2 * i) - 1);
        for (int j = 1; j <= ns; j++) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        for (int k = 1; k <= na; k++) {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

It produces an output that is identical to your program's output:

```
Enter height: 5
     *
    ***
   *****
  *******
 *********
 *********
  *******
   *****
    ***
     *
```